# Can I delete a disk encryption password I have forgotten?

Tags: password, encryption, password-recovery

Ubuntu 16.4.1 - I know the original password that I have set up, but I added a more complex password that I have forgotten. Can I find this password? Is it possible to delete a password that I don't know?

There are 8 password slots, and the more slots have passwords, the less secure I feel.

Comment: is it windows or mac ?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 16.04.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi by dumping your header you can see what keyslots are in use - "0" is always the first entered key - the command for this is `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdXx`. After this you should be fine with running `cryptsetup luksDelKey <key slot number>` - it will ask you to verify the process by typing a password already set.